# Calculate Passengers on each Destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am trying to calculate the number of passengers traveled to each destination. Here is some sample code, if that helps.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE #PAX
(
  FLIGHT_NO INT,
  SEG INT,
  DEP VARCHAR(3),
  ARR VARCHAR(3),
  First_Class INT,
  Economy INT
)
```

**DML:**

```
INSERT INTO #PAX(FLIGHT_NO, SEG, DEP, ARR, First_Class, Economy)
SELECT 220, 1, 'STL', 'JFK', 11, 166
UNION ALL
SELECT 220, 2, 'STL', 'DXB', 13, 21
UNION ALL
SELECT 220, 3, 'JFK', 'DXB', 11, 150;
```

I would like to know how many passengers have flown to JFK and DXB.

**Expected Result:**

```
SELECT 'STL', 'JFK', 24, 187
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JFK', 'DXB', 24, 171
```

My Attempt so far:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT DEP, SUM(First_Class) AS First_Class, SUM(Economy) AS Economy FROM #PAX GROUP BY DEP HAVING COUNT(DEP) > 1 
),
LEG2 AS
(
SELECT ARR, SUM(First_Class) AS First_Class, SUM(Economy) AS Economy FROM #PAX GROUP BY ARR HAVING COUNT(ARR) > 1
)
SELECT #PAX.DEP, #PAX.ARR, CTE1.DEP, LEG2.ARR, 
SUM(CTE1.First_Class) AS First_Class, SUM(CTE1.Economy) AS Economy
,SUM(LEG2.First_Class) AS First_Class, SUM(LEG2.Economy) AS Economy
FROM #PAX LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE1 ON #PAX.DEP = CTE1.DEP
LEFT OUTER JOIN LEG2 ON #PAX.ARR = LEG2.ARR
GROUP BY #PAX.DEP, #PAX.ARR
, CTE1.DEP, LEG2.ARR
```

Comment: Your database does not have passenger-level information, so you cannot determine this from the summary data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I just posted a sample example. In reality, it I am joining another table for passenger information.

Comment: @DaleK I've added my attempt to the original post now.

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have provided, you can use GROUP BY query to group based on the ARR column:

```
SELECT ARR, SUM(First_Class) AS 'TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS', 
       SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_ECONOMY', 
       SUM(First_Class) + SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_PASSENGER'
FROM #PAX
GROUP BY ARR
```

Modified Answer as per Comments:

```
SELECT DEP, '' AS ARR, SUM(First_Class) AS 'TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS', SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_ECONOMY', SUM(First_Class) + SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_PASSENGER'
FROM #PAX
WHERE DEP NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ARR) FROM #PAX)
GROUP BY DEP
UNION ALL
SELECT '' AS DEP, ARR, SUM(First_Class) AS 'TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS', SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_ECONOMY', SUM(First_Class) + SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_PASSENGER'
FROM #PAX
WHERE ARR NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(DEP) FROM #PAX)
GROUP BY ARR
```

Until the rules are provided to ascertain the specific DEP and ARR column values, the same could not be determined as per sample data and expected result provided.

UPDATED ANSWER (Based on Provided Data):

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DEPCOL = '' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT(ARR) FROM #PAX WHERE ARR != ARRCOL )
        ELSE DEPCOL
       END as 'CALC_DEP',

       CASE 
        WHEN ARRCOL = '' THEN (SELECT DISTINCT(DEP) FROM #PAX WHERE DEP != DEPCOL ) 
        ELSE ARRCOL
       END as 'CALC_ARR',


       TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS, 
       TOTAL_ECONOMY
FROM
(
SELECT DEP as DEPCOL, '' AS ARRCOL, SUM(First_Class) AS 'TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS', SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_ECONOMY', SUM(First_Class) + SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_PASSENGER'
FROM #PAX
WHERE DEP NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ARR) FROM #PAX)
GROUP BY DEP
UNION ALL
SELECT '' AS DEPCOL, ARR AS ARRCOL, SUM(First_Class) AS 'TOTAL_FIRST_CLASS', SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_ECONOMY', SUM(First_Class) + SUM(Economy) AS 'TOTAL_PASSENGER'
FROM #PAX
WHERE ARR NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(DEP) FROM #PAX)
GROUP BY ARR
) AS tflight
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant how many passengers have flown from STL to both JFK and DXB as their final destinations. Like some passengers might have flown from STL-JFK and got down and some sitting in the plane. While some others boarded in JFK and flew to DXB along with the STL passengers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo! As mentioned in the original post, the output should have both DEP and ARR fields.

Comment: Your ARR locations can technically be JFK or DXB. What rule do you have in place to ascertain that for the resulting query, the selected ARR value is flights coming from STL is JFK. Ditto with your DEP columns which could technically be STL OR JFK?

Comment: It's the flight number that ascertains it.

Comment: Which column is is the Flight Number?

Comment: I haven't added it earlier because it wouldn't make any difference but I updated my original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203271/discussion-between-angelo-and-julaayi).